# Why Is Component Filtering on The Google Maps API not working?

Tags: api, google-maps

I am having trouble with the Google Maps Geocoding API.

In particular, I am having trouble getting component filtering with "country" to work.

I have defined an api call function like so:

```
def extract_lat_lng(address_or_postalcode, country_code, data_type = 'json'):
    api_key = "your-api-key-here"
    endpoint = f"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/{data_type}"
    country = f"country:{country_code}"
    params = {"address": address_or_postalcode, "key": api_key, "components=": country}
    url_params = urlencode(params)
    url = f"{endpoint}?{url_params}"
    r = requests.get(url)
    if r.status_code not in range(200, 299): 
        return {}
    latlng = {}
    try:
        latlng = r.json()['results'][0]['geometry']['location']
    except:
        pass
    return latlng.get("lat"), latlng.get("lng")
```

I try to call:

```
extract_lat_lng('Santiago, EM','MX')
```

I get back the results:

```
Out[74]: (-33.4488897, -70.6692655)
```

These are the geocoordinates for Santiago in Chile.  I wanted the geocoordinates for Santiago in Mexico (state = EM).

Is there a way to get this working?

Comment: What is your expected result? I don't see a "Santiago" in the State of Mexico. My source is Wiki, so it could be wrong. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Municipalities_of_the_State_of_Mexico

Answer (score 0):

The solutions is to remove "=" from the param variable like so:

```
params = {"address": address_or_postalcode, "key": api_key, "components": country}
```